# Change URL of Active_Admin Resource | how to iverwrite AA routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to change the route of a resource from "/partner_programms" to "/programmangebot".

is there a way to do it with active_admin without put in my own route to routes.rb?

ActiveAdmin do:

```
       admin_categories GET        /admin/categories(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                    POST       /admin/categories(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
 new_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
edit_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
     admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                    PUT        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                    DELETE     /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
```

when i do

```
#routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :categories, :path=>"Kategorien"
end
```

i get unnamed routes

```
               admin_categories GET        /admin/categories(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            POST       /admin/categories(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
         new_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
        edit_admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
             admin_category GET        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            PUT        /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            DELETE     /admin/categories/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            GET        /admin/Kategorien(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            POST       /admin/Kategorien(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            GET        /admin/Kategorien/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            GET        /admin/Kategorien/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            GET        /admin/Kategorien/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            PUT        /admin/Kategorien/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
                            DELETE     /admin/Kategorien/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/categories"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way would be to rename the resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Partner::Programms, as: 'Programmangebot' do
```

This changes all references to the resource.

Answer (score -1):

You could add routes via another file as described at [Rails Best Practices – split route namespaces into different files](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/73-split-route-namespaces-into-different-files). I don't know how you'd remove the existing route.

correct answer of comment:

tried adding admin/Kategorien after ActiveAdmin.routes(self) and got the same result as you, the new routes were unnamed. If I put the admin/Kategorien route above ActiveAdmin.routes(self), then the my Kategorien routes were named, and the ActiveAdmin ones were unnamed.

Comment: no, thats not. i tried to overwrite the routing. i edited the question with code

Comment: I tried adding admin/Kategorien after `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` and got the same result as you, the new routes were unnamed. If I put the admin/Kategorien route *above* `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`, then the my Kategorien routes were named, and the ActiveAdmin ones were unnamed. Still, I'm confused. Your original question says you want to change the route **without** adding it to routes.rb, but your example changes routes.rb.

Comment: By "unnamed routes", I guessed you mean the routes without named helpers (like "new_admin_category"). The helpers are a convenience, but the routes without helpers still function.

Comment: ya, at least it would be nice to configure it in AA itself. but its great. just put my own routes above the AA routes and it works. great. thanks!